# Custom Facebook Login button doesn't respond in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, facebook-login

Hey so I have a custom facebook login button on my app with the following code (executed after the button is clicked):

```
-(void)clickedLoginButton{
    NSLog(@"clicked button");
    FBSDKLoginManager * manager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc]init];
    [manager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"finished");
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error occurred");
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"Cancelled");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"job done");
        }
    }];
}
```

It prints out "clicked button" but for some reason does not print anything that happens inside the handler. However, I am confused because when you click the facebook login button it takes you to facebook where it says "You have already authorized " and then takes me back to the app screen. Not sure why it's not calling anything inside the handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had multiple instances of the app downloaded onto the phone so when I deleted all of them and then tried again it worked fine.